# Do you still call it a "snack" if it consists of various items?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, singular-vs-plural

Let's say I buy potato chips, a rice ball, and a beer. And I consume all that at midnight.

Can I still call it a midnight snack? Or I should call it midnight snack**s**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Snacks, snacking, to have a snack**

to have a snack. [basically any small amount of food from a sandwich to a fruit bar or even leftovers]. **Anything that you eat at a time that is not a regular meal time (breakfast, lunch and dinner) and that is not enough to call a meal**. This usually does not include alcohol. Snacks can be eaten at any time: afternoon, morning, in the middle of the night, etc. Morning snack, midnight snack etc.

There are healthy snacks and junk food snacks. A snack could be comprised of various items. A cookie, an apple and a glass of milk might be a healthy snack. Potato chips would be less healthy. Alcohol is not usually used as part of a snack. But never say never.

Snacks can be bought at a store. **Snacks can also be "created" by the snacker**.

You can take a small plate, put some leftover stew on it, eat it and call that a snack.

That said, you could say: I had a midnight snack of beer, potato chips and a rice ball. Because that is not enough to make a meal really. **And because, you, the snacker are calling it a snack**. It's up to you, really.

Finally, some people prefer to have small or small-ish meals and also have a snack between, say, lunch and dinner. Or after dinner, before going to bed.

[How odd,the word snacker is red lined here. Ha ha.]

Comment: So it seems like I can use both "snack" and "snacks" in my example above? I'm a bit confused, ha.

Comment: You're right; you can use either one. But it might help if you edited your question and told us the full sentence you imagine saying, like: "I ate some midnight snacks;" or, "I had a midnight snack," or, "I'm getting ready to have some midnight snacks." (All of those seem fine to me, btw.)

Comment: @J.R. Why don't you put in your own answer?? I have covered  most bases. "I'm getting ready to have some midnight snacks" in the plural is not one I would entertain. I gave the base form: to have a snack. Generally, it's one thing and can made up of various packages. If you "buy snacks" in a package, eating them is still: I'm having a snack. Generally, the plural is not used to refer to eating between meals if referring to a **particular instance of snacking**.

Comment: ***I had a snack*** this afternoon around 3  o'clock. Oh? What did you have? I had a small package of cookies and an apple. The activity is not the thing eaten. Compare: Don't forget to pack snacks for the kids.

Comment: @Lambie - I was only answering Alex's follow-on question in that comment, which is why I didn't leave it as a stand-alone answer. Personally, I don't have a problem with [having some snacks](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22having+some+snacks%22&safe=active&tbm=bks&start=10&biw=1354&bih=764), but I don't want to get in a prolonged debate about it here.

Comment: @Lambie Your answer confused me more than it cleaned up things. You start by saying the OP's chips and beer are snacks, but your cookie and a glass of milk is a snack?

Comment: @MrLister: Here is the ***point***: ***a snack is a meal between meals***. Also, ***a snack is  thing you can purchase in a package at a store***. Therefore, we ***generally*** would say; I had a midnight snack [a meal between meals]. And not: I had midnight snacks with an s.  A midnight snack can be comprised of snacks (things in packages) but the activity or event is not: midnight snacks. Unless you are saying: He had midnight snacks every day of this life. I hope that "cleans" it up.

Comment: @Lambie OK, but then your answer shouldn't start with the word "snacks", which is the first thing we read after the OP's "call it snack or snacks".

Comment: @MrLister I think you are confusing a single **snack** (comprised of multiple items) and **snacks** (multiple instances of a single snack). It's the same thing as sitting down for an individual **meal**, yet eating several **meals** in a day. If somebody has **midnight snacks** then they have one **snack**, finishes it, and then returns for another sometime later. If multiple instances of a singular item can't be pluralized, and understood that way, then much of English would need to be changed . . .